Receiving data from a web client
[Edit] Please jump to the bottom for the latest edits...
I am developing a console application using a TcpListener to receive requests from clients:
mWebSocketServer = new TcpListener(ipWebSocketAddr, mcintWebSocketPort);

ipWebSocketAddr contains 192.168.5.73, mcintWebSocketPort contains 443. I start listening and create a thread to manage clients and received data:
try { 
    mWebSocketServer.Start();
    mWebSocketThread = new Thread(() => webSocketServer());
    mWebSocketThread.Start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    FrmMain.UpdateTaskbar(ex.ToString());
}

The thread:
public async void webSocketServer() {
    Byte[] arybytData = new byte[1024];
    while (mblnRunTillStopped == true) {
        try {
            TcpClient tcpClient = mWebSocketServer.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine(FrmMain.strTimeStampMsg("webSocket client connected"));
            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            int i;
            while ((i = stream.Read(arybytData, 0, arybytData.Length)) != 0) {
                string strRX = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(arybytData, 0, i);
                Console.WriteLine(FrmMain.strTimeStampMsg("From web-client: " + strRX));
                string strTX = "Acknowledge";
                byte[] arybytTX = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strTX);
                stream.Write(arybytTX, 0, arybytTX.Length);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(mcintWebSocketServerThreadSleep);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            FrmMain.UpdateTaskbar(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

A client would send data with:
webSocket.send(cstrSendMsg);

cstrSendMsg contains msg=US.  In the C# application I report all received data to the console, what I see is:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.5.73:443
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://192.168.5.73
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Sec-WebSocket-Key: rlhgDPkLxwNFeA6pMZtNwg==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits

I don't see anything that resembles the data, where do I look for that?
I'm using Chrome (Version 131.0.6778.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)) for the client and to debug.
This is the client-side script:
    webSocket = new WebSocket(cstrServerSocketIP);
    webSocket.onclose = (event) => {
        DebugMsg("webSocket.onclose");    
    };    
    webSocket.onerror = (event) => {
        DebugMsg("webSocket.onerror");   
        if (typeof event == "object" && typeof event.data != "undefined") {
            DebugMsg(event.data);    
        }
    };    
    webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
        DebugMsg("webSocket.onmessage: " + event.data);
    };
    webSocket.onopen = (event) => {
        DebugMsg("webSocket.onopen: " + event.data);    
    };    

cstrServerSocketIP contains ws://192.168.5.73:443/, after single stepping through this I can see in the Chrome debugger:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.5.73:443/' failed: 

I have no idea why because no reason is given.  This is a sample from the server side of a client interaction:
Received:
21-11-2024 14:46:03.937> From web-client:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.5.73:443
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://192.168.5.73
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Sec-WebSocket-Key: iURnr6DRWqF2wbtypFsLig==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits

Response:
HTTP/1.1 1-1 Switching Protocols
Connection: Update
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: AFRdDliX+pqKnGCr652yekplUAI=

Is there something wrong with the Sec-WebSocket-Accept value?
This is what I do:

Take the received value associated with Sec-WebSocket-Key
Build a new string which is the value associated with Sec-WebSocket-Key concatenated with "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
Create a SHA1 using the result of 2.
Base64 encode result from 3.
Write result from 4 into header Sec-WebSocket-Accept.

[Edit2] I've modified the original thread so the same thread should work for both HTTP and Websockets, the modification, which is a work in progress, but it seems to have broken the web-server:
        public async void httpServer() {
            while (mblnRunTillStopped == true) {
                try {
                    HttpListenerContext ctx = await mListener.GetContextAsync();
                    HttpListenerRequest req = ctx.Request;
                    if (req.IsWebSocketRequest) {
                        HttpListenerWebSocketContext ctxWS = await ctx.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null);
                        Console.WriteLine("HERE");
                    }

It doesn't get to the Console.WriteLine("HERE");
I still see in the client debugger:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.5.73:443/' failed: 

[Another Edit] Can someone verify if I have prepared response header correctly?
He is a sample request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.5.73:443
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://192.168.5.73
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Sec-WebSocket-Key: GysunwWXiQEX05sMpW7Y1g==

I then take the value GysunwWXiQEX05sMpW7Y1g== and append 258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11
string strKey = strWebSocketKey + mcstrWebSocketMagicString; 

Then I create a SHA1 key:
byte[] arybytSHA1 = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strKey));

And finally base64 encode:
strWebSocketAccept = Convert.ToBase64String(arybytSHA1);   

The response:
HTTP/1.1 1-1 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: PuuJ05IxiUQuB9aBpBZCIBKCU38=

Something is clearly wrong because the client shows:
file.js:33 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.5.73:443/' failed

I found this post: generate "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" from "Sec-WebSocket-Key"
And have used the answer to compare and verify mine is correct, but still the client reports Failed ?

In the C# side you're using a raw socket, but you're connecting to it with a websocket protocol, so you need first to implement an HTTP server, and on top of that the websocket protocol, then you get the data itself. Perhaps you want to use a more ready-made webserver library instead?

@Alejandro, I did it the other way around, I already have a HTTP server implementation listening to port 80.  To receive websocket requests I added a TcpListener on port 443.

Also: why do you make it public async void? You shouldn't use async void except for EventHandlers but also, there is nothing that uses the await keyword inside that method.

@Fildor, thank you, I have dropped the async, its because I cut and paste from my HttpHandler thread that does use await and async.

"To receive websocket requests I added a TcpListener on port 443." - then that's perhaps in conflict with your running webserver. 443 is the default port for TCP/HTTPS

@Fildor, there shouldn't be any conflict as least nothing is reported and the web-server is listening to port 80 only.

Websockets is an HTTP extension, you just listen like a normal webserver and, based on some headers, switch to websocket (those headers are shown in your example). You need to handle those and respond accordingly to get the actual data.

@Alejandro, I want to keep the HTTP webserver threads and the Web-Socket threads separate.

@SPlatten threads have nothing to do with the fact that WebSockets aren't the same thing as Sockets and can't be implemented with just a TcpListener. You need to use the same code you already did for the HTTP server and add support for the WebSocket protocol.

Or use ASP.NET Core's WebSocket support. ASP.NET Core uses a separate thread for each request already. All you really need to do is call app.UseWebSockets() to set up web sockets and then use controllers or Miminal API endpoints to accept requests and, if it's a WebSocket request, use it.

@PanagiotisKanavos, I cannot use the same code for both the HTTP Server and WebSockets, because the HttpListener will not accept the prefix "ws://", error: Only Uri prefixes starting with 'http://' or 'https://' are supported.

That doesn't mean HttpListener can't work with WebSockets. WebSockets runs on tof of HTTP or HTTPS. There are a lot of samples that show how to use context.AcceptWebSocketAsync etc to handle requests. And, as this SO question shows, the prefix doesn't really matter apart from establishing whether HTTP or HTTPS is used. Have you actually tried using HttpListener and AcceptWebSocket ?

@PanagiotisKanavos, so I added: mListener.GetContext().AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: null);  now the http server doesn't work at all.

As it turns out its the simplest of mistakes that cause the problems, In my original post I pasted in the problem:
HTTP/1.1 1-1 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: PuuJ05IxiUQuB9aBpBZCIBKCU38=

The above response was built on something I found online, the actual problem and error is on the very first line:
1-1

It should and must be:
101

Interestingly and amazingly, my son suggested I try using https://claude.ai, which I did, I opened it up and pasted in the HTTP request headers, then posted under it, "What's wrong with the above?", instantly it came back with the correction.

There are several problems in the code so it's actually easier to show how to create a WebSocket server using either ASP.NET Core or HttpListener.
.NET Console client
The client is a Console application created with dotnet new console that just sends strings and prints the response until Ctrl+C is pressed. It does the bare minimum to send a string and ensure the socket is closed at the end:
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;

Console.WriteLine("Starting");

var cts=new CancellationTokenSource();
Console.CancelKeyPress+= (_,_) => cts.Cancel();

var socket = new ClientWebSocket();
await socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://localhost:5237/ws"), cts.Token);
Console.WriteLine("Connected");
var buffer = new byte[1000];

try{
    while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.Write(">> ");
        var msg = Console.ReadLine();
        var msg_bytes=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
        await socket.SendAsync(msg_bytes, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

        var result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
        Console.WriteLine("<< {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count));
    }
}
finally
{
    await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure,null,CancellationToken.None);
}

Chrome/JS Client
Something similar can be done in Chrome's Console window, provided CORS restrictions are followed:
const exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5237/ws");
exampleSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log(event.data);
};
exampleSocket.send("Here's some text that the server is urgently awaiting!");

The CORS policies in browsers like Chrome won't allow JS to call a URL outside the page's domain. To fix this, open http://localhost:5237 first (or whatever port is used by ASP.NET Core) and then try to use the console.
The Network tab of the browser's Dev Tools will show the individual messages and headers passed between the browser and server too.


This works with HttpListener as well. ASP.NET Core sets the Server response header while HttpListener doesn't, unless it's set in code :

Server
The most basic server can be another Console application that creates an HttpListener that waits for WebSocket connections. The listener is created outside the loop. .GetContextAsync() waits for an incoming connection and, if it's a WebSocket one, processes it and echoes the content back using Echo :
using System.Net;
using System.Net.WebSockets;

using var server = new HttpListener();
server.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:5237/");
server.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Started");
while (true)
{
    var context = await server.GetContextAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Incoming");
    if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        WebSocketContext ctx = await context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null);
        await Echo(ctx.WebSocket);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
    }
}

This code can process a single request at a time, although it's asynchronous. It doesn't check the route either.
A better option is to use ASP.NET Core's built-in WebSocket support. The minimal example doesn't require more lines of code, but brings request and thread management, along with the rest of the hosting infrastructure. And of course, it's a lot easier to add authentication etc.
using System.Net.WebSockets;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseWebSockets();

app.MapGet("/ws", async ctx =>
{
    if (ctx.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        using WebSocket webSocket = await ctx.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
        await Echo(webSocket);
    }
    else
    {
        ctx.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
    }
});

app.Run();

In both cases the Echo method is the same, taken from the ASP.NET Core WebSocket docs example :
async Task Echo(WebSocket webSocket)
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    var receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(
        new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

    while (!receiveResult.CloseStatus.HasValue)
    {
        await webSocket.SendAsync(
            new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, receiveResult.Count),
            receiveResult.MessageType,
            receiveResult.EndOfMessage,
            CancellationToken.None);

        receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(
            new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
    }

    await webSocket.CloseAsync(
        receiveResult.CloseStatus.Value,
        receiveResult.CloseStatusDescription,
        CancellationToken.None);
}


Thank you, however I am using JavaScript and it looks like you are calling built in ASP objects which must do a lot of what I'm trying to do, it doesn't show how the response headers are correctly built implementing Sec-WebSockjet-Accept, so I cannot accept this answer.

I've used the logic and example keys from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers to verify that strWebSocketAccept string is correct and I get exactly the same result but the client still shows Failed???

The point of this answer is to show the minimum needed so you can see how different it is from anything you posted until now, and why HttpListener works perfectly fine, even though you insisted it doesn't. You don't need the Sec- headers for WebSockets to work. If you want security, use ASP.NET Core instead of trying to roll your own. As for a Javascript client, you never posted JS code that uses the webSocket object. MDN doesn't have .NET documentation. As for headers, I didn't post any code that displays the headers. That doesn't mean there are no headers

I would like to know what is causing the client to report "Failed", since there is no text to go with it.  There seems to be a lot of conflicting information online and mis-information.

You didn't post any client code, just event handlers, and the server code you already tried  would never work because its full of critical errors, like using the wrong listener, creating multiple ones in a loop, mangling text by using 7-bit ASCII etc. Why don't you try the ASP.NET Core code first, to see how things actually work? Besides, you can call WebApplication.CreateBuilder inside a desktop application too.

I've now found out what was causing it to show Failed, it turned out to be as simple as changing ws:// to wss://, although having that it still failed but on a longer timeout.

The ASP.NET Core code doesn't need a long timeout. const exampleSocket = new WebSocket( "ws://localhost:5237/ws"); in Chrome's console works as long as CORS policies are observed. And exampleSocket.send("Here's some text that the server is urgently awaiting!"); works, immediately receiving a response

@SPlatten I added minimal JS client code that works in Chrome and shows the headers are handled by HttpListener as well as ASP.NET Core.
